# como importar um projeto play framework 2.5 para o eclipse

Tags: java, play-framework

Olá como poderia importar um projeto lay framework para o eclipse, nas versões anteriores apenas o comando eclipse dentro do projeto já era o bastante mas agora a documentação está um pouco confusa nesse aspecto.

Answer (score 1):

Apos iniciar o console do play, de o camando `eclipse` na pasta do projeto:

```
$ play new projeto_01
$ cd projeto_01
$ play

[projeto_01] $ eclipse
```

o comando eclipse vai gerar os arquivos para importar o projeto. Depois é só abrir o eclipse e ir em `File->import`, n janela que aparecerá, escolha `General->Existing Projects into Workspace` e click em `Next`. A próxima janela pedira o caminho do projeto (tente deixar o seu projeto `play` no mesmo diretório dos projetos eclipse) e selecione seu projeto `play` e confirma.

Comment: sua resposta serve para as versões anteriores, mas para a versão atual não.

Comment: pelo que diz na documentação, para todas as versões o método de configuração é o mesmo, tem como importar esse plugin no build.sbt `"com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0"`. Entretanto, eu dei uma olhada no repositório do sbt e esse plugin não estava disponível, talvez tenha removido o plugin de suporte. Mas você pode configurar os arquivos `.classpath` e `.project` para identificar como um projeto eclipse.